# SQL Results data from rows to columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

I have created a query which returns me the following:

```
[Branch], [SaleDate], [ReceiptNo]
```

My `[SaleDate]` column is a concatenation of the SaleMonth and SaleYear in the format '01/2013'

What I require is these results to come out as a form of a table with:

A Column for each `[SaleDate]`

A Row for each `[Branch]`

The value for each Row/Column will be a COUNT(`[ReceiptNo]`)

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT ReceiptNo, SaleDate, Branch
   FROM tablename
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(ReceiptNo)
  FOR SaleDate IN([01/2013], [02/2013], [03/2013], ...)
) AS p;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80614/3)

---

To do this dynamically instead of listing the values of `SaleDate` manually, you have to use dynamic SQL, like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(SaleDate)
                      FROM tablename
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT ReceiptNo, SaleDate, Branch
   FROM tablename
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(ReceiptNo)
  FOR SaleDate IN(' + @cols + ')) AS p;';

execute(@query);
```

- [**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80614/5)

Comment: Hi, Thats Great, thanks, is it possible to add an ORDER BY in there so that the columns are in date order e.g 01/2013 | 02/2013 etc.

Comment: @Richard - Yes, in the dynamic version put the `ORDER BY` in the statement which get the columns concatenated which is using the `STUFF` clause, see this updated demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80614/17

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant. Thank you for your help